# pthread_create passing arguments

Tags: c, pthreads

What is wrong with this code? In `function()`, the offset value is printing as `-1`. I expect it to be value `10`. 
Offset with `-1` is giving `sum = -1000`.
**Note**:offset is stored in heap memory.

test() prints expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_t thread[2];
int sum = 0;

void*
function(void *arg){
   int i;
   int offset = *((int *)arg);
   printf("offset = %d \n",*(int *)arg);
   for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
      sum = sum+offset;
   }
   printf("\n sum = %d \n",sum);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void test(void* val){
   int offset = *((int *)val);
   printf("Inside test function.offset = %d \n",offset);
}

int main(){
   int ret;
   int *offset = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

   *offset = 10;
   test(offset);

   ret = pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, &function,(void *)offset);
   if(ret!=0)
      printf("pthread create error \n");

   pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Inside test function.offset = 10
offset = -1
sum = -1000
```

Test platform: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, GCC 4.8.4, Linux kernel 3.13.0-57-generic.

**gdb output:**

```
Breakpoint 1, function (arg=0x7fffffffdd4c) at mutex_lock.c:11
11         int offset = *((int *)arg);
(gdb) p *((int *)arg)
$4 = -1
```

Comment: Works for me on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 with GCC 6.2.0 — it produces `offset = 10` and `sum = 10000` after I tweaked the format to ensure that there could be no confusion between negative numbers and the offset.  What platform are you testing on?  Note that if you ever activate the second thread for which you've allocated storage, all hell will break loose and all bets are off unless you add code to protect (synchronize, serialize) access to `sum` (and possibly access to `offset`, though if you don't change that for the two threads, you will probably be OK).

Comment: i am using Ubuntu -14.04    gcc --version
gcc - 4.8.4

Linux kernel - 
3.13.0-57-generic

Comment: That's intriguing. I upgraded to 16.04 LTS in my VM, and was running a home-built GCC 5 or 6 version anyway before I upgraded.  I don't have a good explanation for why you are getting a wholly different result.  The most I can offer is the observation that it is not self-evident that there's a bug in your code.

Comment: Prints `offset =10 sum=10000` for me on Ubuntu 16 with gcc 5.4.  The only thing I can think of is that if `offset` goes out of scope before the thread is joined.  But in your sample program above, that is definitely not happening.  Perhaps in your case, `pthread_join` is failing and main is exiting before the thread has a chance to run.  This is the exact code you are running too?

Comment: How exactly do you compile this?

Comment: And does your "real" code also only create *one* thread?

Comment: Yes. I am exactly running the same code posted above. I compile it using   "gcc -g -pthread  mutex_lock.c"